# miniDLNA (ReadyMedia) disconnects after few minutes

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, dlna

I'm using *miniDLNA* on my Pi 3 and I'm encountering weird issues that I've never encountered before, after setting up the Pi from scratch.

### Setup

- Pi connected via internal WiFi and via ethernet
- DLNA via *miniDLNA* on NTFS-mount (also accessible via *Samba*)

  - listening solely on the ethernet adapter (`eth0`)

### Problem

The smartTV, which I'm using to watch video files, is disconnected from the DLNA device a few minutes after playback has been started.
At least, this is what the TV tells me.

There's no warning or related info message in the *miniDLNA*-log.

However, on rare occasions the connection is stable and allows to play for 30+ minutes.

#### Probably Networking Problem

Sometimes SSH loses the connection at these exact moments as well but I'm not quite sure if this may be due to the SSHD option `ClientAliveInterval`.
If I try to SSH into the Pi immediately again I often get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pi3: No address associated with hostname
```

which resolves automatically after a few seconds.

There's no information about possible causes in *syslog*. I solely get notified about established SSH sessions and there's literally no output between intermediate logins after such a disconnect:

```
Feb 21 22:27:20 pi3 systemd[1]: Started Session c67 of user sebschlicht.
Feb 21 22:34:08 pi3 systemd[1]: Started Session c68 of user sebschlicht.
```

### Quintessence

My DLNA and probably the whole Pi is occasionally disconnected and sometimes remains unreachable via hostname for few seconds, rendering my DLNA service practically unusable.

What is causing DLNA to disconnect? May it be a random network disconnect? If yes, how to debug that situation? Do you have any idea what may cause it?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I have the same problem regarding the `minidlna`. It plays for about 10 minutes and disconnects. But sometimes it works well. However, I have never been thrown out of my `ssh` shell.

Answer (score 0):

May be a corruption in one of the minidlna files. After a power failure experienced similar problems on openSUSE Leap 15.3. Removed minidlna.conf after some network trouble shooting which recreate files after minidlna stop and restart. Since  recently upgraded from openSUSE Leap 15.1 to 15.3 I could not say if the problem was caused by the upgrade or power failure since I did not use the WD Media player since. I copied the minidlna.conf file back in place and restarted minidlna. This successfully resolved my issue. No more strange errors reported. Only experienced the issue on Western Digital Media player. Playing the same media on Lenovo M10 Plus Tablet with VLC caused no problems. After reset both systems work without problem